# Add ActionLink in JqGrid column in ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid, html.actionlink

I am using jqGrid with ASP.NET MVC 3 and Razor.

I am looking to add 2 columns to the jqGrid along with the rest of the columns.

The columns I want to add are

- Edit
- Delete

These columns value I want to be `ActionLink`.

**How do I add an ActionLink to a Column of a JqGrid ?**

Please guide me on this.

Update 1: with help from @user1534482 I tried this but did not work

```
colModel: [
    ...
    { name: 'Open', formatter: 'prepareLinks' },
    ...
],

 function prepareLinks(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return "@Html.ActionLink("Open this","Test")";

}
```

javascript error message :

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error]   

return "<a href="/SomeController/Test">Open this</a>";

SomeController (line 92, col 41)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @tpeczek and @user1534482

I finally got the solution,

```
colModel: [
    ...
    { name: 'Open',
        formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            return '<a href="/ControllerName/Test/?myId=' + cellvalue + '">' + "Open" + '</a>';
        } 
    },
    ...
],
```

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at *showlink* [predefined formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter).

There is no code in your question so I don't know how complex your scenario is, but in general code like this should be enough:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#gridId").jqGrid({
        colNames: [..., 'Edit', 'Delete'],
        colModel: [
            ...
            {name:'EditAction', formatter:'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '@Url.Action("Edit")' } },
            {name:'DeleteAction', formatter:'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '@Url.Action("Delete")' } }
        ],
        ...
    });
</script>
```

The row id will be added automatically (you can control how with `idName` option). If you need to pass some additional parameters take a look at `addParam` option in the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter).

**UPDATE**

For clarification on how the final link is generated, you can use this formula:

```
"<a " + ((op.target) ? "target=" + op.target : "") + " href=\"" + op.baseLinkUrl + op.showAction + "?" + op.idName + "=" + rowId + op.addParam + "\">" + cellvalue + "</a>"
```

Where `op` is the `formatoptions` object and `cellvalue` is the value for the column from data you have pasted to the jqGrid.

Comment: thanks. but I tried `{ name: 'Open', formatter: 'showlink', formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: '@Url.Action("Test")', idName: 'FolderId'} },` but still no link was generated only id's were shown in the column

Comment: @Yasser I have updated the answer with details on how the link is being generated, please check if you are returning correct value for the column in your data (in general it should be the text for the link).

Comment: thanks to your link I managed to get this done by using the `formatter` option, I have also posted an answer of what I have finally used. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

u can use ur own formater like

```
 colModel: [

        { name: 'colname', formatter: linkbuilder   },
    ],
```

and

```
and add function

function linkbuilder(cellval, opts, rwdat, _act) {
    return "@Htm.ActionLink()";
}
```

Comment: function calling in formatter : 'prepareLinks' without quotes

Comment: and dont forget to backslash your double quotes in js string return "@Html.ActionLink(\"Open this\",\"Test\")";

Comment: or use '@Html.ActionLink("Open this","Test")'

Comment: I did it using the `formatter` option I have added my solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12404792/1182982). Thanks !